# What is the smallest size of CAdES signature?

Tags: signature, cades

CAdES signatures are usually huge, they contain certificates, possible full chain, and even source data enveloped in it. This is very impractical if we want to sign every file in the system for integrity purposes.

What is the smallest possible detached and **valid** CAdES signature? (To keep in the log or in separate p7s files.)